# How to inject properties in ehcache configuration file?

Tags: xml, ehcache, properties-file

Is it possible to inject some properties in ehcache.xml?

For example I have different property files, each belonging to an environment:

`my_project_name.local.properties`

`my_project_name.test.properties`

`my_project_name.int.properties`

`my_project_name.prod.properties`

each of them containing properties for a different environment.

I'd like to inject in ehcache.xml the property `maxByteslocalHeap` as following:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
     updateCheck="false" monitoring="autodetect"
     maxBytesLocalHeap="${my_project.cache.maxBytesLocalHeap}">
     .....
</ehcache>
```

`my_project.cache.maxBytesLocalHeap` is defined in each property file shown above and has different values according to the environment where my application is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no, across all existing Ehcache version at this time (latest 2.10.2 and 3.1.3).

The long answer to your question depends on the Ehcache version:

- Ehcache 2.6.x to 2.10.x only supports property substitution for the disk path configuration at the CacheManager level. The pattern to use is the classical `${my.prop}`.
- Ehcache 3.0.0 up to 3.1.2 does not support any property substitution.
- Ehcache 3.1.3 and above support property substitution in all schema position that accept text. Again, the pattern to use is the classical `${my.prop}`. Note that it means with your example, you will not be able to substitute sizing information because the XSD enforces that the value is a strictly positive number.

The latest limitation listed here could be lifted - the development team was just not sure it was worth the effort. So if this is something you believe Ehcache should provide, please drop a mail on the [ehcache-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ehcache-users) google group.